# Values in Value List dependent on values chosen in a previous Combobox

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-access-2010

I am looking for a way to adjust the values possible to choose in a combobox dependent on the choice made in another combo box, but there is a catch:
The values in the comboboxes are given in a value list (not from a query).

At the moment I have to comboboxes:
Combobox1:
1, 
2, 
3, 
4

Combobox2:
1.1, 
1.2, 
1.3, 
2.1, 
2.2, 
3.1, 
4.1

All these options are manually typed in. I am looking for a way to only show 1.1-1.3, when the option "1" is chosen in Combobox1.

Is it also possible for the comboboxes to show e.g. "1.1 - Assessment", but only "return" the value 1.1?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You'd have to change the `.RowSource` property of Combobox2 in the `.AfterUpdate` Event of Combobox1.
2. Yes, with 2 columns in the Combobox, and the first column being the bound one. RowSource would then be e.g.

```
1.1;Assessment;1.2;something else
```